# Debug ZSim with Visual Studio Code

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am trying to use VSCode debugger for a complex application zsim (https://github.com/s5z/zsim). GDB works fine on it but I do not know how to set launch.json to support zsim debugging in VSCode.

zsim is a simulator based on intel PIN (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/81205/Pin/html/index.html#DEBUGGING). As the document says, it has several distinct approaches for debugging. When in GDB console, I append "-pause_tool 5" to PIN command to force whole application to stop temporarily and output program's PID and additional symbol location for you to manually add. During the five seconds, I have to launch gdb, attach that PID and execute add-symbol-file provided by PIN.

Fortunately zsim wraps up all arguments in gdb to form one command looks similar to this: "gdb -p 15326 -ex set confirm off -ex add-symbol-file /build/debug/libzsim.so 0x7ffff5db17a0 -s .data 0x7ffff642ab80 -s .bss 0x7ffff642c540 -ex handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint -ex set confirm on -ex c". I tried to modify my launch.json to the following:

```
"request": "attach",
"processId": "15326",
```

It does not work. When I select the correct PID, VSCode turns to debug mode but nothing happens. Then after 5 seconds ZSim starts simulating as it is not being attached. Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: have you found any way to do this in a terminal?

Comment: @Z-Y00 I think it is intended to debug in a terminal. During the pause phase, you can start gdb and attach the pid of zsim.